# How can I style react semantic components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can I add CSS for react semantic UI ? I am using create react app. I have installed semantic-ui-react and CSS CDN: https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage/?fbclid=IwAR3ZBaJfpxHGiNcAvophLp7IAPO-gHZfDvSOLs8h-n0-_29ncPoOdjwCX7o#content-delivery-network-cdn

loginForm.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Form, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";
import styles from './loginForm.css';

const LoginForm = () => (
<Form className={styles.formStyle}>
<Button className={styles.buttonStyle}>Login</Button>
</Form>
);

export default LoginForm;
```

loginForm.css:

```
.formStyle {
margin-left: 500px; 
margin-top: 100px;
width: 550px;
}

.buttonStyle {
border-radius: 18px;
width: 200px;
background-color:#3865FE;
}
```

Above CSS code is not working for loginForm.js why so ? I also tried following :

```
<Form style={styles.formStyle}>
    <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}>Login</Button>
  </Form>
```

Above code is also not working.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet according to this, everything should works fine unless your cra app is outdated, did you try to use your css module without semantic ? Maybe semantic override your css, thus it's working but not visible

Comment: @FabienGreard So what is the fix for this problem ? I am using create react app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you're setting the value of className incorrectly.
Here is the modified version of your code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Form, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";
import from './loginForm.css';

const LoginForm = () => (
  <Form className='formStyle'>
    <Button className='buttonStyle'>Login</Button>
  </Form>
);

export default LoginForm;
```

and for loginForm.css

```
.ui.form.formStyle  {
  margin-left: 300px ; 
  margin-top: 100px ;
  width: 550px ;
  height: 400px;
 }

.ui.button.buttonStyle {
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:#3865FE;
}
```

thanks @funJoker for suggesting me how to edit semantic-ui style.

Comment: What changes do I need to make in loginForm.css ? Also why import styles if you are not using it in component ?

Comment: You don't have to make any changes in css file. Since you want to add your own custom css style in semantic component you have to import the css file in LoginForm.js file.

Comment: I guess you're confused about how to use imported css in js file. Actually react has JSX syntax which is similar to html so just like in html when you add style style to your component you set it by either "id" or "class". In react you can do this by importing the css file and setting the component style by setting the value  of className props. 
You should got throught the below link of React about JSX.
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: Your code is not working see this screenshot ->https://imgur.com/a/J2UAkty

Comment: Why this code works -> https://gist.github.com/aditodkar/0c40c2cc875581d0cd1c9eb4f1751699 I couldn't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183604/discussion-between-varun-arya-and-fun-joker).

Comment: In your code answer edit it to `import './loginForm.css`